# Fixing C code for arduino uno board - ultrasonic module HC-SR04

Tags: c, math, arduino-uno, platformio

I recently wrote code that is meant to measure the range detected by the arduino uno ultrasonic module HC-SR04. However, the range value printed is constantly wrong. The values for range are never accurate and frequently jump 3000cm to 5cm.

I would greatly appreciate some help with this DIY project. Thank you everyone! :D

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

// Define macros for bit manipulation
#define bitSet(reg, n) (reg |= 1 << n)
#define bitRead(reg, n) (reg & (1 << n))
#define bitClear(reg, n) (reg &= ~(1 << n))

// Define constants for clock frequency and baud rate
#define FOSC 16000000
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR FOSC / 16 / BAUD - 1

// Define pin assignments
#define TRIG_PIN PB1
#define ECHO_PIN PB2

// Declare volatile variables for storing time and distance
volatile unsigned long startTime = 0;
volatile unsigned long endTime = 0;
volatile unsigned long duration = 0;
volatile int distance = 0;

// Function prototypes
void USART_Init(unsigned int ubrr);
void USART_Transmit(unsigned char data);
void txString(const char *pStr);

// Function to initialize USART communication
void USART_Init(unsigned int ubrr)
{
  // Set baud rate
  UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr >> 8);
  UBRR0L = (unsigned char)ubrr;

  // Enable receiver and transmitter
  UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);

  // Set frame format: 8 data bits, 1 stop bit
  UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

// Function to transmit a single character over USART
void USART_Transmit(unsigned char data)
{
  // Wait for empty transmit buffer
  while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)))
    ;
  // Put data into buffer, sends the data
  UDR0 = data;
}

// Function to transmit a string of characters over USART
void txString(const char *pStr)
{
  while (*pStr != '\0')
  {
    USART_Transmit(*pStr);
    pStr++;
  }
}

// Interrupt service routine for Timer 1 capture event
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{
  if (bitRead(PINB, ECHO_PIN)) {
    startTime = ICR1;
  } else {
    endTime = ICR1;
    duration = endTime - startTime;
    distance = duration * 0.017 / 2;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  // Initialize USART communication
  USART_Init(MYUBRR);

  // Set trigger pin as output and echo pin as input
  DDRB |= (1 << TRIG_PIN);
  DDRB &= ~(1 << ECHO_PIN);

  // Set timer 1 for input capture mode with noise canceler and prescaler of 8
  TCCR1B |= (1 << ICNC1) | (1 << ICES1) | (1 << CS11);

  // Enable input capture interrupt
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << ICIE1);

  // Enable global interrupts
  sei();

  // Main loop
  while (1)
  {
    // Trigger ultrasonic sensor
    PORTB |= (1 << TRIG_PIN);
    _delay_us(10);
    PORTB &= ~(1 << TRIG_PIN);

    // Transmit distance over USART
    char formattedDistance[20];
    sprintf(formattedDistance, "Distance: %d cm\n", distance);
    txString(formattedDistance);

    _delay_ms(500); // Wait for 1 second
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use floating point on ancient 8 bitters, because they have no FPU and will perform terribly by inserting a floating point software lib. Particularly you should not use floating point calculations inside a time-critical ISR.

Comment: `distance = duration * 0.017 / 2;` => `distance = duration * 17 / 2000`

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the interrupt routine: `ICR1` is a 16-bit register. But you assign it to an `unsigned long`, which is 32-bit. If you have a timer overflow, there is no natural overflow of your duration measurement.

You have to declare `startTime`, `endTime`, and `duration` as `unsigned int`s. It is best practice to use `#include stdint.h` so you can specify the size of your integers, which may vary from one platform to the other.

As Lundin pointed out, keep your ISR as short as possible, e.g.

```
#include <stdint.h>

volatile uint16_t duration = 0;
volatile uint16_t startTime = 0;
volatile uint16_t endTime = 0;

// Interrupt service routine for Timer 1 capture event
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{
  if (bitRead(PINB, ECHO_PIN)) {
    startTime = ICR1;
  } else {
    endTime = ICR1;
    duration = endTime - startTime;
  }
}
```

And then convert to a distance in your main loop. Usually on MCUs without a floating point unit (FPU), you would want to make the calculations in integer arithmetics.

```
// Convert to distance
uint16_t distance = (duration * 17) / 1000 / 2;
```

By the way, I would also explicitely reset, start, and stop the timer when you want to measure, so you are sure that the time is measured at the right moment.

Comment: you should `#include <stdint.h>`, not `#include "stdint.h"`.

Comment: `((uint16_t)twice_the_distance) >> 1;` this is absolutely unnecessary. Any modern compiler that doesn't know how to optimize divisions by powers of 2 or any other constants would be better thrown into the trash bin. And `(float)duration * 0.017f` => `duration * 17 / 1000`